# Stack/transpose and duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a lot of data in a format I need to rearrange.

Current table: Rows of subjects with values, each column corresponding to a time point

[image]

I need each "subject" to be duplicated x times (x being the amount of time points, in this case 12) and then (preferably) the values to inhabit it's own column (just transposed essentially) making each subject look like this:

Preferred table outcome, three columns: Subject, time, value

[image]

I'm usually ok doing it manually, but this time it's just so many "subjects". Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: Thank you! This did what I needed! :)